# Azure Web App swap causes site unavailable for couple of minutes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Lately something has changed in Azure LB and Swap mechanism.

Whenever we swap into production a web app from staging the site/service becomes unavailable for couple of minutes.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: What is the start time of your web app? If it takes a really long time, the automatic warm up which happens during the swap might not be able to finish in time.

Comment: Another thing is that in general, even if the swap failed to warm up the site, your site should still come up with the first cold request (it would just take longer). Can you repro the issue even with an empty/blank site?

Comment: Why does the swap need to warmup the site? The site is already running in staging.

Comment: The fact that it is running is not guaranteed. Imaging you would only deploy new binaries of your web app to the staging slot and then do the swap right away. The staging version was not running and once targeted as production, visitors would hit cold requests. The swap operation ensures that whatever is swapped into the production slot is warmed up regardless whether you hit it manually or not right before that.

Comment: When you say the site becomes unavailable - do you mean you get http 503 error or it just take long time to load?